# Why Laravel Sanctum returns always 404

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-sanctum

I use Laravel with a Vue SPA. The application runs very well sins a half year.

Now, we need a new instance for further tests. The new instance is on the same server as the dev. I like to continue to use dev and if it works, to deploy with deployer to the test instance. So, the new root is `current/public`

I deployed the application. The start page (login) works. But then, the csrf request returns a 404.

I changed the .env file to the new domain. I checked it twice.

Then i searched in google for other solutions, no way.

I cleaned cache, routes and config. No better result. I checked the store in the browser. Everything looks ok. The session cookie and als the xsrf token are there.

Is it possible, that the server doesn't accept any header? It's an nginx

Actually I have no Idea to where I have to searcht....

Comment: the index, root route, works but no other routes work? this is usually a URL rewriting / pretty URL misconfiguration of the webserver

Comment: @lagbox yes right. I will check it

Comment: I found it. This line was missing in the sites-enabled file: ` return 301 https://$host$request_uri;`